# Group with different background colors in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I have a report that uses grouping in SSRS. The group is collapsed on load and when I expand each group, I can see the individual records. I have a field for each row that shows if its an "Error" and "Info". I did give a different background color for the row like this

```
= IIF(Fields!Loglevel.Value = "ERROR",  "Maroon", "NoColor")
```

and it shows me erros with a different background color.

But what I am trying is to give the whole group a background color if there is at least one error inside it. Can anyone suggest me a way to do this? I tried for backgroup color for the group and I don't see it. Please  suggest a way!

Thanks

Comment: Note `NoColor` is not a valid color, instead try using `Transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum up when Loglevel.Value = "ERROR" using an IIF statement, but you need to do it for the SCOPE of your group.

The scope is the name of the group, eg tblMain_Group1, or whatever you entered when you created the group

Then use that as the criteria for your background colour for the data row

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!Loglevel.Value="ERROR",1,0),"tblMain_Group1")>0,"Maroon","Transparent")
```